# Java linked list within a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to do a little project I found online which is creating a Library Catalog of books and users.

I created 3 classes - Book, User, Manager. Manager has all the methods of checking out books, updating late fees, returning books etc. All these methods take place on a single user.

So if a user wants to check out a book, the manager calls the checkoutBook method on that user along with the book/s and checks them out. One problem I ran into was with late books. I want to be able to tie multiple late books to a single user. Using two separate lists here is too much of a hassle.

So I opted for a linked list within a linked list. But how exactly do I insert an element into the initial list and link it to the second list?

I.e. here is my code:

```
private LinkedList<User> userList = new LinkedList<User>();

private LinkedList<LinkedList<Book>> lateList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Book>>();
```

userList is simply a list of whoever has checked out a book. In my lateList, I want to be able to insert a user within the first list, and a number of late books in the second list tied to that particular user.

How would I go about doing this? I tried to find some info online but it usually refers to placing a linked list within another linked list via the add method. Is there a good way of doing this or am I better off designing a separate class (or user a better data structure) to do this?

Comment: You really should create associations between classes, and follow an Object Oriented approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is, instead of having a linked list of linked lists of books, just have a linked list of late books within your user class. Then you can add methods to add/delete books from the list as you see fit. This approach makes more sense to me because the late books are essentially owned by the user, and this way you don't have to keep track of a user's late books by matching indices and tying them to another linked list.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll do that. Thanks.